# C# how to call async await in a for loop

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, async-await

I am developing a quartz.net job which runs every 1 hour. It executes the following method. I am calling a webapi inside a for loop. I want to make sure i return from the GetChangedScripts() method only after all thread is complete? How to do this or have i done it right?

Job

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    try
    {
        var scripts = _scriptService.GetScripts().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logProvider.Error("Error while executing Script Changed Notification job : " + ex);
    }
}
```

Service method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ChangedScriptsByChannel>> GetScripts()
{
    var result = new List<ChangedScriptsByChannel>();
    var currentTime = _systemClock.CurrentTime;
    var channelsToProcess = _lastRunReader.GetChannelsToProcess().ToList();

    if (!channelsToProcess.Any()) return result;

    foreach (var channel in channelsToProcess)
    {
            var changedScripts = await _scriptRepository.GetChangedScriptAsync(queryString);

            if (changedScriptsList.Any())
            {
                result.Add(new ChangedScriptsByChannel()
                {
                    ChannelCode = channel.ChannelCode,
                    ChangedScripts = changedScriptsList
                });
            }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 8 days ago there was a formal [announcement](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/248) from the **Quartz.NET** team stating that the latest version, [3.0 Alpha 1](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/2016/08/16/quartznet-3.0-alpha1-released.html) has full support for `async` and `await`. I would suggest upgrading to that if at all possible. This would help your approach in that you'd not have to do the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` -- which is typically a code smell.

> How can I use `await` in a for loop?

Did you mean a `foreach` loop, if so you're already doing that. If not the change isn't anything earth-shattering.

```
for (int i = 0; i < channelsToProcess.Count; ++ i)
{
    var changedScripts =
        await _scriptRepository.GetChangedScriptAsync(queryString);

    if (changedScriptsList.Any())
    {
        var channel = channelsToProcess[i];
        result.Add(new ChangedScriptsByChannel()
        {
            ChannelCode = channel.ChannelCode,
            ChangedScripts = changedScriptsList
        });
    }
}
```

Doing these in either a `for` or `foreach` loop though is doing so in a serialized fashion. Another approach would be to use `Linq` and `.Select` to map out the desired tasks -- and then utilize `Task.WhenAll`.